# Kant Critique of Pure Reason, how is time subjective to human intuition yet objective in regard to appearances?

Tags: kant, time, critique-of-pure-reason

I'm confused on a section in the Critique of Pure Reason. Kant says "Hence time is merely a subjective condition of our (human) intuition (an intuition that is always sensible-- i.e. inasmuch as we are affected by objects); in itself i.e., apart from the subject, time is nothing. Nevertheless, time is necessarily objective in regard to all appearances and hence also in regard to all things that we can encounter in experience"(A35).

Could someone explain what he means by time being a subjective condition of human intuition but also objective in regard to things we encounter in experience?

Comment: First off, who isn't confused. Secondly, what do "subjectivity" and "objectivity" mean?

Comment: Kant is describing conditions of knowledge of the "transcendental subject", an idealized version of rational human with senses ("sensible intuition"). Time is relative to this type of subjects, hence subjective, for radically different subjects (like God) it would be "nothing". On the other hand, it is a necessary condition of experience (which takes the form of "appearances") for *all* transcendental subjects (in particular, all humans), hence objective "in regard to all appearances".

Comment: @Conifold thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Kant speaks of space/time and appearance, he really speaks of two things:

1. Time (and space) being the specific form of the object as it is given to our senses and therefore as it *appears* to our senses. This is related with Kant's **formal idealism**, i.e. the view that even *a priori* cognitions are only valid as far as they relate to intuitions, specifically: formal (or pure) intuitions of space and time (see the footnote at B161). Therefore we can only know *appearances* or, specifically, sensuous appearances according to the nature of our sensibility (which is contingent, unlike thought itself).
2. Time (and space) being *merely subjective* or *ideal* or, in other words, being, in some substantial way, mere features of the subject. Kant agrees with Leibniz that space and time must have this feature as they're *purely relational*. So additionally to time and space being forms of sensible objects (which I find uncontroversial), Kant speaks of them being *merely* subjective. This is Kant's thesis of the **transcendental ideality** of time.

Kant says in the *Prolegomena* that one should read his doctrine as being essentially *formal idealism*. It's quite important to distinguish these two theses of Kant. The first one says that pure thought derives all content from sensuous intuition (which must have some form - and, in our case, perhaps in all cases, says Kant, it's space and time). The second one, much bolder (by today's standards), says that space and time are produced, in some sense, by the subject or *reflect the features of the subject* (the word *ideal* means that something, ex. some distinction, is present only *in thought*).

In the passage you cite, Kant asserts his second thesis, which most of us now find quite odd. But whenever he speaks of "things in themselves" being distinct from "phenomena" he means the first thesis: that we know objects according to some form which is the form of our sensibility. If we abstract from this form, we cannot know anything (Kant explains it well  in a footnote in the *Preface* to the second edition of the first *Critique*).

This is important because some people confuse the two thesis and conclude that Kant's distinction between appearances/phenomena and things in themselves means that we can know merely our own subjective creations. Kant says no such thing but his discussion often is so difficult if you don't realise the Leibnizian background of the second thesis and its independence from the first thesis that it's easy to get lost. Good luck!